# What does %(something)s mean?

Tags: python

I accidentally found this code on Github:

```
cmd_template = ' -T --some-arg1 --some-arg2 --arg3 %(split)s -o %(output)s %(input)s'
```

I know what `%s` means, but what does `%(split)s` (and others) mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a form of string formatting.  It means take the value from the dictionary with key `"split"` and substituted it in the string at that spot using the `%s` (string) format.  For example, if you write:

```
x = '%(foo)s' % {'foo': 'bar'}
```

`x` will equal the string `'bar'` (Try it!).

Note that it is more common to see positional arguments with `%` formatting:

```
x = '%s %s' % ('bar', 'baz')
```

and the tuple is used to format this string as `'bar baz'`.

---

Finally, this answer wouldn't be complete without saying that these days, it is very common to see the same thing done with the `.format` method:

```
x = '{foo}'.format(foo='bar')  # same as x = '%(foo)s' % {'foo': 'bar'}
x = '{} {}'.format('bar', 'baz')  # same as x = '%s %s' % ('bar', 'baz')
```

or,

```
x = '{0} {1}'.format('bar', 'baz')
```

if you're stuck with python2.6. . .

Comment: @Grienders: `x` is the variable being set.

Comment: @Grienders -- It's just an example.  In the code you're looking at, likely there is a `cmd_template % some_dict` later in the code where `some_dict` is a dictionary with keys `'output'`, `'input'` and `'split'`.

Comment: Then it's not "x" but "foo".

Comment: that's such an existential question.... where is x?  really, though... is it in my mind or is it in the computer or somewhere else entirely?  now, next... why is x?  (sorry)